# Overlaying image on mapbox map?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have a mapbox satellite map on which I need to load an external image of the seas as an overlay (the image has transparent countries).

This is the map:

```
 var mymap = L.map('map', {
      center: {lon: 12.39258, lat: 41.69906},
      zoom: 5,
      maxZoom: 8,
      zoomControl: true
    });

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets-satellite',
    accessToken: '<mytoken>'
    }).addTo(mymap);
```

and this is the code to load the overlay image:

```
 var imageUrl = 'http://.....',
    imageBounds = [[30.1875, -18.125],[45.650167938232421875, 36.101667938232421875]];
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(mymap);
```

The imageBounds are those of the image I am loading. The image has been generated from a system with EPSG4326 coordinates. The result is that the image is drifted from the base map, and the country borders don't overlap perfectly.

Comment: Adjust your image to fit using a desktop GIS. QGIS >Raster>Georeference using openlayer web plugin or ESRI ArcMap Georeferencing with ESRI Basemaps. The borders in either of these basemaps should register fine at this scale.

Comment: suggestion for a GIS application for Mac?

Comment: Qgis works on mac

Comment: I have tried with ArcGis online, and my layer is perfectly positioned on the map... What else?

Comment: Perhaps confirm your imageBounds. Note the precision on the first coordinates is much less than the second. It may also be worth you adding a screenshot of the drifted image over the base map to help better assess what you are up against.